# Rc::new_cyclic - borrow of possibly uninitialized variable

Tags: rust

I have this `Emulator` class.

```
pub struct Emulator {
    cart: Rc<RefCell<Cartridge>>,
    bus: Rc<RefCell<Bus>>, /* requirs access to cartridge, dma, ppu, and joypad */
    cpu: Rc<RefCell<M6502>>, /* requires access to bus */
    ppu: Rc<RefCell<PPU>>, /* requires access to cartridge */
    dma: Rc<RefCell<DMA>>, /* requires access to cpu, ppu, and bus */
    joypad: Rc<RefCell<Joypad>>
}
```

You can see that its components depend on each other. I decided to use `Rc` and `Weak` to maintain this cyclic relationship.

I have difficulty figuring out how to create new instance of this structure.

```
impl Emulator {
    pub fn new(fname: &str) -> Self {
        let cart_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Cartridge::new(fname)));
        let weak_cart = Rc::downgrade(&cart_ref);

        let ppu_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(PPU::new(weak_cart.clone())));
        let weak_ppu = Rc::downgrade(&ppu_ref);

        let joypad_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Joypad::new()));
        let weak_joypad = Rc::downgrade(&joypad_ref);

        let mut bus_ref: Rc<RefCell<Bus>>;
        let mut cpu_ref: Rc<RefCell<M6502>>;

        let dma_ref = Rc::new_cyclic(|weak_dma| {
            bus_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Bus::new(
                weak_cart.clone(),
                weak_ppu.clone(),
                weak_joypad.clone(),
                weak_dma.clone()
            )));
            let weak_bus = Rc::downgrade(&bus_ref);

            cpu_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(M6502::new(weak_bus.clone())));
            let weak_cpu = Rc::downgrade(&cpu_ref);

            RefCell::new(DMA::new(weak_cpu.clone(), weak_ppu.clone(), weak_bus.clone()))
        });

        Emulator {
            cart: cart_ref,
            bus: bus_ref,
            cpu: cpu_ref,
            ppu: ppu_ref,
            dma: dma_ref,
            joypad: joypad_ref
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I got this error

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `bus_ref`
  --> src\emulator.rs:38:38
   |
38 |         let dma_ref = Rc::new_cyclic(|weak_dma| {
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `bus_ref`
39 |             bus_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Bus::new(
   |             ------- borrow occurs due to use in closure

error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `cpu_ref`
  --> src\emulator.rs:38:38
   |
38 |         let dma_ref = Rc::new_cyclic(|weak_dma| {
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `cpu_ref`
...
47 |             cpu_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(M6502::new(weak_bus.clone())));
   |             ------- borrow occurs due to use in closure
```

I have no idea how to fix it. I can't think of other combinations. I wonder if I should restructure my code.

Comment: Can you give a Minimal Reproducible Example, possibly a playground too?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae76a75a323de795a237c5eb3fb9d75c

Comment: Ooof, that one is hard. What a spaghetti code of references :D the main problem is that in general, the borrow checker has a hard time keeping track of things that depend on whether or not a closure has been executed. In your case, the initialization of `bus_ref` depends on the fact that the closure has been executed exactly once. But you only give it to `Rc::new_cyclic` as an argument, and proving that the function internally executes the closure is too complex for the borrow checker. (That's at least my understanding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot borrow an uninitialized variable in a closure, because then when it is dropped the compiler will have to know whether it was initialized but it has no way to track that inside the closure (not that it completely cannot, but anyway this is something Rust does not support). See [issue #41124](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41124).

The way I would handle this is by sprinkling some `Option`s and `.unwrap()`s here and there:

```rust
let mut bus_ref: Option<Rc<RefCell<Bus>>> = None;
let mut cpu_ref: Option<Rc<RefCell<M6502>>> = None;

let dma_ref = Rc::new_cyclic(|weak_dma| {
    let bus_ref_ = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Bus::new(
        weak_cart.clone(),
        weak_ppu.clone(),
        weak_joypad.clone(),
        weak_dma.clone(),
    )));
    let weak_bus = Rc::downgrade(&bus_ref_);

    let cpu_ref_ = Rc::new(RefCell::new(M6502::new(weak_bus.clone())));
    let weak_cpu = Rc::downgrade(&cpu_ref_);

    bus_ref = Some(bus_ref_);
    cpu_ref = Some(cpu_ref_);

    RefCell::new(DMA::new(
        weak_cpu.clone(),
        weak_ppu.clone(),
        weak_bus.clone(),
    ))
});

Emulator {
    cart: cart_ref,
    bus: bus_ref.unwrap(),
    cpu: cpu_ref.unwrap(),
    ppu: ppu_ref,
    dma: dma_ref,
    joypad: joypad_ref,
}
```

Not perfect, but works.